# Java 7 - Mac + Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I've got an eclipse java project I need to open and run, it was built in Java 7, the default on my mac is appearing as java 6. When I right click the project > build path > try to change the java version .. it says Java 7 (unbound).

I've got java 7 update 51 installed on the mac.

I've tried installing java 7, but eclipse isn't recognising it.
[image]

Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse does not automatically find all Java instances, but has a list of known JREs.

To add your newly installed JRE, open Preferences, select the *Java/Installed JREs* page, and try search to find your new engine. If search does not yield results, select the Add... button, on the first page, select Standard VM, and then add '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home' as the Java home (or something similar).

Answer (score 2):

Click that "Installed JREs" button and all will become clear.

Assuming that you have successfully installed [an Oracle JDK 7 for Mac](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html), you should be able to configure Eclipse to use that JRE. Here is my setup (using JDK 7u51):

[image]